Inserting a table into a known table with docx
Good day all,
I'm working on a very specific automation which requires a table being added into an existing table.
So far I can replace key words in a dictionary. However, I also want to be able to insert tables and text in these rows. I have the veriable index which is a touple of the row object and the cell object but I have no idea how to manipulate the .add_table function of docx to ensure a table gets added within a cell rather than at the end of a document.
Heres my code:
from docx import Document

#Replace key words function
def write_doc(template_path, output_path, layup_data):
    doc = Document(template_path)

    #Table 6 is the table which I'd liek ot add more tables in to in my specific problem
    for row in doc.tables[6].rows:
        for key, value in layup_data.items():
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                    for run in paragraph.runs:
                        #Add operation index if it is replaced.
                        if key == run.text:
                            index = (row, cell)
                            run.text = run.text.replace(key, value)

                                      
    doc.save(output_path)


#key words to replace
if __name__ == '__main__':
    layup_data = {
        '{{word}}': "new word"
    }


#Read and write paths
    template_path = 'template.docx'
    output_path = 'new_file.docx'

    write_doc(template_path, output_path, layup_data)


I'm thinking including a table in position within the tempalte document is the way forward. I will update as soon as I figure out how to identify a nested table.
